# How do we take the closure of $\{f\neq 0\}$ if the support of $f:U\color{red}\subsetneq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ is to be determined?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

In most literature, the support of a function is defined as the closure of the set where the function does not vanish. With this in mind, let's consider the support $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ of $f:U\color{red}\subsetneq\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. I was wondering how to take the closure of $\{f\neq 0\}$ in determining $\mathrm{supp}(f)$.

I used to read Munkres' *Topology*; there is a theorem that addresses the dilemma of finding the closure of a subet $A$ of a subspace $Y$ of a topological space $X$. As the theorem puts it, the closure of $A$ in $Y$ is the intersection of $Y$ and the closure of $A$ in $X$.

Now, here's the biggie: what is the definition of $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ accepted by the general public? In evaluating the support, should we seat ourselves in the subspace $U$? Or instead the notation $\mathrm{supp}(f)$ is reserved for the closure obtained by putting ourselves in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thank you.

Comment: Since the domain of $f$ is $U$ you have to take the closure in the subspace topology of $U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f: (X, \tau) \to \Bbb{R}$ continuous function. Then $\operatorname{supp}(f)=\operatorname{cl}_X{\{x\in X : f(x) \neq 0\} }$

$U\subset \Bbb{R^n}$ then consider $(U, \tau_U) $ as a euclidean subspace of $(\Bbb{R^n}, \tau_{std}) $

Suppose $f:U\subset \Bbb{R^n}\to\Bbb{R}$

Then $\begin{align}\operatorname{supp}(f)&=\operatorname{cl}_U{\{x\in U : f(x) \neq 0\} }\\&= U\cap \operatorname{cl}_{\Bbb{R^n}}{\{x\in X : f(x) \neq 0\} } \end{align}$